# Spring Batch job status not updated in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration

I have created a Spring batch application where I have configured Remote chunking using AMQ.
referred below example:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#remote-chunking

Application is running fine and able to process chunks in different application instance. However Spring batch related tables are not getting updated with completed status.

Same is working when application is running in single instance.

Can someone help if there is anything extra step I have to introduce to update step and job completion?

Comment: I have got the problem. I have started 2 master and 2 Worker. which is causing error.

Comment: but in my case I can't create Master and Worker in separate module. Is there a way by using I can configure only 1 manager for multiple application instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring profiles for that. This allows you to have a single module with both the manager and worker code and select which one to run when you launch your app. You can find an example here: https://github.com/mminella/scaling-demos/tree/sp1-2018#remote-chunking.